# Animation not working within react native template string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I have a progress bar in react native

```
render(){
    const { progressWidth } = this.state;
    return(
    <Animated.View
    style={{
        backgroundColor: '#5BEBBC',
        width: `${progressWidth}%`,
        height: 154,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
    }}
    />
    )
}
```

and a function which triggers the animation

```
Animated.timing(
    this.state.progressWidth,
    {
    toValue: 100,
    duration: 5000,
    }
).start();
```

But the progress bar doesn't update. It just stays at 0. I have tested with a hardcoded value of '100%' and can see it just fine. 
Can I not use a value inside a template string like that?